# AWS Lightsail with Lamp php8

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I updated Laravel 8 to Laravel 9, it require Php8. Is possible to start an instance on AWS with Lamp8 or is there a way for update?

Comment: Any update on this? I couldn't find php8 in lightsail

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that they have new LAMP stacks available with PHP 8.0, so it is possible from now on.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33360637)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).